# Scala 2.12 and Java 8 SAM interop doesn't compile

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, lambda, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to test a Java 8 class using `rx.Observable` from Scala Test. As per Scala `2.12.0-M3` [release notes](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0-M3/):

> LAMBDA SYNTAX FOR SAM TYPES (EXPERIMENTAL) As of M3, this feature is
>   not yet on by default. You can enable it with the `-Xexperimental`
>   compiler option.
>
> When the option is enabled, then similar to Java 8, Scala 2.12 allows
>   instantiating any type with one single abstract method by passing a
>   lambda.

However, using Gradle and IntelliJ, I can't get the following to compile:

```
val o: rx.Observable[util.Map.Entry[String, _ <: util.Collection[String]]] = ???
val scheduler = new TestScheduler()
scheduler.createWorker().schedule(_ => o.foreach { }) // The argument is an Action0, which has a SAM void call()
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

group = 'name.abhijitsarkar.scala'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = false
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-feature", "-Xexperimental"]
    targetCompatibility = "1.8"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.0-M3'
    compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-experimental_2.11:2.0.3'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12.0-M3:3.0.0-M12'
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about 2.12.0-M3, but with 2.11.7 it seems like I sometimes (always?) need to explicitly extract the lambdas into declared values of the corresponding SAM type. (Which is a headache that I would hope goes away soon.)

Comment: @DavidMoles < 2.12.x Java 8 support is experimental. 2.12 onwards it's supposed to be official.
http://scala-lang.org/news/2.12-roadmap/

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: @nafg I don't remember, it's been 4 months.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> scheduler.createWorker().schedule(_ => o.foreach { }) // The argument is an Action0, which has a SAM void call()
> ```

That would try to pass a "function" with one argument (rather an anonymous instance of an interface/trait with a 1-argument SAM). The `_` just indicates that you don't use that argument in the body. `Action0`'s `call()` takes 0 arguments, so try it with `() => o.foreach { }` instead.